# Footer troubles

Tags: css, position, footer, extend, fixed

http://www.olli.es/kushiri/search.html

What I want is to make the middle section (the two green shaded sections) extend downwards when the window gets too big and the footer to stick to the bottom but not go higher than minimum height when the window gets too small.

Anyone know how to approach doing that?

Hm there must be a proper way to make footers, and I'm just really ignorant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/seler/shNhV/